# Identifiy Rows with spaces in date column

Tags: sql, date, syntax, syntax-error

I have a large database with a column that has date formating and it contains "dates", "empty values" and probably "values with only spaces".

```
date_column
-----------
2022-03-24
2022-03-15
2021-05-10

2020-02-15
2022-01-10
2021-05-10

2019-10-08
2020-01-10
```

I would like to know how can I identify in SQL the rows that have spaces. Because when I extract the data, in excel I see that I have more "empty values" than what I'm able to count with SQL.

What I'm trying to do to identify rows with "empty values" is:

```
WHERE date_column = ' '
```

However I'm receiveing the following message:
"SYNTAX_ERROR: '=' cannot be applied to date, varchar(1)"

Can anyone help me?
Regards

Comment: Looks like your `date_column` is actually of `date` datatype (great). A `date` cannot have spaces, it can only have a valid date or NULL. So you probably need to select `WHERE date_column IS NULL`. Don't trust how Excel formats your dates (ever)

Comment: Side note, SQL syntax varies by vendor and version, so always include your dbms in question tags (not just `sql`)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the LIKE operator?

```
WHERE date_column LIKE %' '%
```

The % means that there can be characters before or after the space.

```
WHERE date_column LIKE ' '
```

Might also work for you.

Edit: HoneyBadgers comment might be the problem in your case, be sure to try that one first.